# position icons relative to another icon

Tags: c#, algorithm, position

I have an icon on a grid. I need to place other icons relative to this icon. A max of 3 icons can be next to each other. If there are more than 3 icons, start a new "row". My algorithm is placing my icons in the wrong place. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

wrong result with 4 icons. `Where xref=500`, `yref=550`, and `imgWidthAndHeight=20`:
[image]

correct result with 6 icons:
xxx
xxx
x

the first "x" is the referenced icon. `xref` and `yref` are the coordinates of the original icon, and `imgWidthAndHeight` is the dimensions of the referenced icon.

```
    void placeImages(int xref, int yref, int imgWidthAndHeight)
    {
        int xCopy = xref;
        int yCopy = yref;
        int numberOfImgs = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            Icon newImg = new Icon("test.jpg", new Size(imgWidthAndHeight, imgWidthAndHeight));

            //if we have more than 3 images lined next to each other...
            if (numberOfImgs++ == 3)
            {
                numberOfImgs = 0;
                //...we reset the x position
                xCopy = xref;
                //and move the y position down using the size of the image
                yCopy = yref + imgWidthAndHeight;
            }
            else
                //otherwise we place the image next to the previous one
                xCopy += imgWidthAndHeight;              

            //and create the location using these calculated coordinates
            Point? location = new Point(xCopy, yCopy);
            
            //add the image to the diagram
            page.diagram.AddImage(newImg, location);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show an image of your expected result and your actual result. It would make it easier to understand your question. I do note that your code comment says "we reset the x position" and then proceeds to set `yCopy = xref;` which seems strange (perhaps the naming of your variables is misleading?).

Comment: I apologize. I added an image of the result I'm getting. The icons are all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm required is pretty simple. Just divide your loop counter by the column count (3) and, if the remainder is 0 then reset the column index and increment the row index, otherwise increment the column index.

```cs
const int columnCount = 3;
var rowIndex = -1;
var columnIndex = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (i % columnCount == 0)
    {
        rowIndex++;
        columnIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        columnIndex++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", rowIndex, columnIndex);
}
```